# Java nested for related query

Tags: java

Why isn't this structure acceptable? Anyway it returns a boolean value right??

```
public boolean a()
{

    if(condition)
    {
        if(condition)
        {
            if(condition)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: if all controll flows results in a value being returned it is acceptable

Comment: @ Dixon : You should understand that if one of the if conditions are not satisfied, it will not return anything.

Answer (score 4):

It's not valid because there is a possibilty where nothing is returned. Your method is declared as returning a boolean value, so it MUST return a boolean value at some point in the code before the method is finished, regardless of the inner logic. If your if-statement `if (condition)` is false, the method doesn't have another return statement, so the code won't even compile. To fix this, add a "default" return value:

```
public boolean a()
{
    if(condition)
    {
        if(condition)
        {
            if(condition)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not valid because you need to do a  return  some default value (`return`) .

What `if`  conditions not satisfied ??

valid is :

```
public boolean a()
    {

        if(condition)
        {
            if(condition)
            {
                if(condition)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    return false;

    }
```

As a side note,To make your code mode readable,I suggest

```
  if(condition && condition && condition) 
        {
         return true;
        }
  return false;
```

Prefer to read    [**jls-14.17**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#)

Answer (score 0):

Though the method returns `true` when the condition is satisfied, it doesn't specify a return value when the condition *isn't* satisfied. The method should cover all the code paths (read conditional statements).

Answer (score 0):

As the answers above correctly state, you absolutely *have* to return something in Java. C doesn't really care.

In order to avoid this I would recommend decreasing the level of nesting to do something like

```
boolean value=false; //default return
if(cond && cond)
    return value;
if(cond)
    return false; //if you want to be more specific
if(cond)
    value=true;

return value;
```

so a value gets returned no matter what. On the plus side, readability increases